# Using a more recent .deb version of hplip than standard for that OS

Tags: package-management, scanner, hplip

I am running 18.04 up to date, with hplip 3.17.10 installed. According to package search this is the standard one for this OS.
However, I recently purchased a new HP multi-function printer. To operate the scanner, hp website says it requires hplip 3.20.5 or higher.

There is a version 3.21.06 listed in the package search for Ubuntu 21.10. Can that .deb be used successfully with 18.04?
Or another solution that's not too in depth?

Comment: Why don't you release upgrade? If you force package versions that don't match your release, it can cause problems. 18.04 only has about 10 months of support remaining, so this is a good motivation to go ahead and take care of the upgrade.

Comment: I installed the latest hplip-3.22.4 in a 32 bit Ubuntu 18.04 virtual machine i have. It ran into some dependency problems while installing I can't tell if that is due to the 32 bit or the 18.04.

Comment: You can peruse the requirements via CLI or on the web, ie. https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/hplip and just looking at that first page I can see some potential pitfalls that @OrganicMarble maybe run into (and *unrelated* to *i386* I believe).   I support Nmath's suggestion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: @Nmath Yes, seems that might be the ultimate answer, I just didn't want to go that far just for printer compatibility.

Comment: @OrganicMarble It was a 32-bit issue. On a 64-bit system, no problem.